# environment and salary vs technology

Tags: salary, work-environment, technology

I'm working in a company with a good reputation, great environment with constructive attitude in all colleagues, no stressful deadlines, and a competitive salary.

The downside is that their technology is really old. They are now slowly introducing a bit of new technologies, But the tasks to migrate to those technologies have been given to other colleagues who have better social skills, or are in a more stable position in the company.

I'm not convinced to leave because I'm concerned that I'd end up somewhere that might have better technology, but a bad environment, with a lower salary, and regretting having left this employer.

I've been here for over 2 years now and am increasingly concerned that I'm not progressing, and that moving on to companies with newer and better technologies may be more difficult the longer I stay here.

I feel like I'm stalling and even regressing.

What would be a wise move for someone in my situation?

Comment: `What would be a wise choice to do?` well what are your goals?

Comment: Why do people seem to want the newest technology as if it is a priori better? It sometimes is the case that the older technology is the better solution for your problem.

Comment: @Brandin Also known as the bleeding edge anti-pattern. Using the newest technology is often *worse*, not better. Since the technology is still not sufficiently tested, and hence, unstable, it receives frequent "upgrades" and this cascades into lots and lots of rework for any project using the technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your employer is not giving you the opportunity to update your skills, do so on your own time and on your own dime.  Take online classes and do freelance projects.  While you are doing that, speak to your manager and ask to be put on some of the projects that are migrating to the newer technologies and float your resume just to see what comes up

Answer (score 2):

I was in a very similar situation just a year ago. The simple answer is that as a developer, working with outdated tech will make you unemployable sooner rather than later.

I was lucky to find a great job, working with a senior dev who enthusiastically helped me catch up on areas of my skills which I had been ignoring over the past 2 years of employment. Almost a year later, I am finally feeling confident about how I would measure up if I were to switch jobs today.

You'll have to make the same judgement call. This will also depend on whether you're working to polish your skills up in your own time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you, I'm a junior web developer and the first company I worked for had old technology running in their system and they were just starting to research on new technology to be used in their system at the time, that's when I was hired to be a regular full-time SSDD(same sh*t... you got it) developer.

I saw that they were trying to add this new technology to their agriculture ERP and I started researching it at home knowing that they would have to have someone to help them with that, long story short, they officially announced at the company that the head of the company was looking for someone to help them with that new technology, and they asked the whole company if anyone had some kind of experience with that new tech and I was like: "I do!"(I'm a sneaky lil' B), I got promoted and the head of the company gave me a bunch of perks (it was a small business).

In my humble opinion you should try to get involved, as you said this is a slow company, so it might be easier to make the difference than in a bigger company, I'm not saying I did, but I wouldn't leave a company like yours(I left my first one because I had to move :( otherwise I would still be working with them to this day).